# How to return a LONGTEXT field as JSON in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I have a products table in which I store the product image paths as a JSON string (LONGTEXT type in MariaDB), however, when I query the database for the list of products using Node.js and send the data to the client-side, it receives the image paths as a string instead of array objects.

Question: is there a way of telling MySQL/MariaDB to return the LONGTEXT fields as JSON, or I will need to create a helper function in Node.js to do this job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using  a convert() JSON

```
 CONVERT( your_long_text_col,  JSON)
```

test

```
select concat('"', CONVERT( '{"id": 1, "name": "Monty"}',  JSON), '"');
```

Comment: I tried this: `SELECT concat('"', CONVERT(imgs, JSON), '"') from products;` however it throws error 1064 near `JSON), '"')`

Comment: which version of mysql   you are using   ?? ...i have used   5.7

Comment: I use 10.4.6-MariaDB

Comment: check if work the concat sample test  .. if work  .. then check for a valid  JSON in your imgs column content ..  if the test not work then your db version don't support convert  to JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you need to migrate from Mysql 5.7 JSON **(json type)** to MariaDB 10.6 JSON **(text type)** you can use custom **JSONTextField** instead of **models.JSONField**

it will not require any data-migrations and can be used without any db changes and will work both for mysql and mariadb

```
from django.db.models import JSONField
from django.db.models.fields.json import DataContains, JSONExact


class JSONTextField(JSONField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return "text"


class JSONTextExact(JSONExact):

    def process_lhs(self, compiler, connection, lhs=None):
        lhs, lhs_params = super().process_lhs(compiler, connection, lhs=lhs)
        lhs = "JSON_EXTRACT(%s, '$')" % lhs
        return lhs, lhs_params


JSONTextField.register_lookup(JSONTextExact)
JSONTextField.register_lookup(DataContains)
```